# The EU cookie directive mandates "consent" often via a popup. Can I block those?

Tags: cookies, popups

The EU cookie directive, a monstrous directive that effectively banned a part of normal economic life, mandates "consent" before cookies can be set. This is often implemented via an annoying repetitive and pointless popup that appears AFTER I have voluntarily accessed the site.

Is there a popup blocking solution that allows you to automatically accept cookies and get rid of the popup so that I never have to think about this again?

Comment: +1 as it is ridiculous. However, it's not always a pop up, some times, for example, the message could be built into the header of the website which remains until dismissed. A pop up blocker won't help.

Comment: -1 because it is not true. It does not simply mandate consent before cookies are placed. It explicitly allows cookies which are functional, and its goal is clear in trying to reduce tracking cookies after the industry failed to regulate itself.

Comment: +1 because it's irrelevant to the user what the directive mandates; those popups *are* annoying.

Comment: I would prefer to block cookie messages that are inline in the header as well.

Comment: There's no way for a webbrowser to detect whether a popup is asking consent for cookies, participation in a survey, login details, ... The closest thing possible would an industry-standard "microformat" CSS name for these cookie popups.

Comment: @MSalters that sounds like a solution. Also, aren't there various stock scripts that would always use the same CSS and button names? I'm sure it could be done, but has it been?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use Adblock Plus then adding [this list (txt file)](https://raw.github.com/r4vi/block-the-eu-cookie-shit-list/master/filterlist.txt) is helpful in blocking a lot of these messages. See [David Thorpe's blog](http://www.dave-thorp.me.uk/2012/12/22/block-the-eu-cookie-popups/) for more detailed advice if needed.

Answer (score -1):

To stop it from happening do the following:
never clear your browsing cookies from within the browser, use Ccleaner to clean all your history, cache, cookies etc, but you can go into *Options* > *Cookies* and double-click on cookies to keep and it will not delete these; your best going into all the sites you visit, then run Ccleaner *Options* > *Cookies* as all the cookies will be there for you to move into the *Keep* section; be sure to keep coming back and updating this list with new sites you visit.

Now every time you run Ccleaner it will clear out everything but these cookies.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain the relatonship between the answer and the question? Assuming I do not care what /cookies/ are set, what does Ccleaner do about the /popups/?